# Show that the union of complete sets is not necessarily complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, complete-spaces

$\textbf{Proof: }$ Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and consider $A_n=[\frac{1}{n},1],n\in\mathbb{N}$. We have that  $A_\delta$ closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ are complete.

Thus $A_n$ is complete in $\mathbb{R},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}=\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$.

$A_\delta\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}$ however it does not have a limit point in $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}$.

Thus $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{A_n}$ is not complete.

I think I got the gist of it, maybe I'm missing some key factors or there could be a better way of proving this. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your union of A_n’s should be $(0,1]$ not $(0,1/n]$.

Comment: If by complete you mean sequentially closed, another example is $B_n=\{1/n\}$ for each $n\in \Bbb N.$  The set $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N 
    }B_n=\{1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}.$ is not complete

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A counterexample is a perfectly valid way of showing that something is not always the case, and you have a perfectly good counterexample.

As for your proof in particular, I don't know what $A_\delta$ is. Actually, if you take the proof that you have, and just erase the two $A_\delta$ that you've written, then it reads just fine, apart from a few grammatical hiccups that have nothing to do with math or logic.

Edit: Apparently I missed that you'd written $\bigcup A_n=(0,1/n]$. That should, of course, be $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

What you did is fine, except that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=(0,1]$.

A simpler example would be to take $A_n=\left\{\frac1n\right\}$. Then each $A_n$ is complete, but$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\},$$which is not.

Answer (score 0):

This proof seems to me unnecessarily complicated. You asked for "a better way of proving this"; here is one.

Let $X$ be any non-complete set.

Let $A_x=\{x\}$ for each element $x$ in $X$.

Then each $A_x$, being finite, is trivially complete, but their union is $X$ which is incomplete.

(Daniel Wainfleet's example above is a special case of this.)

This is so much simpler that I wonder if you haven't misunderstood the question. Are you sure it wasn't asking you to prove that a *finite* union of complete sets must be complete?

Comment: I'm sure I didn't misunderstand the question as I posted it directly from my reader. However I will say that your explanation of this made a lot of sense. Thanks